# Trying to render /admin if there's matching value in mySql database - Nodejs Ejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, ejs

I was working on adding a user system to my node express app. It worked, but now I want to be able to render "/admin" only if the logged user have "Admin" writed in my mySQL DB (in isAdmin field). I don't know if i'm explaining correctly, but I think the best option is to put another "if" in my login controller. I tried a lot of ways but i'm kind of struggling with mySql statement and the third "if" condition.

Here's my login controller :

```
exports.login = function(req, res){
var message = '';
var sess = req.session; 
if(req.method == "POST"){
   var post  = req.body;
   var name= post.user_name;
   var pass= post.password;
   var sql="SELECT id, first_name, last_name, user_name FROM `utils` WHERE `user_name`='"+name+"' and password = '"+pass+"'";                           
   mysqlConnection.query(sql, function(err, results){      
      if(results.length){
         req.session.userId = results[0].id;
         req.session.user = results[0];
         console.log(results[0].id);
         res.redirect('/');
         message = 'Login réussi !'
      }
      else{
         message = 'Mauvaises informations.';
         res.render('index.ejs',{message: message});
      }         
   });
} else {
   res.render('index.ejs',{message: message});
}
```

};

Thanks, and i'm sorry for my shitty skills